# select records both ways from same table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

i have to select records from two tables, but combine them in a way, here is my table

```
loans
----
id
amt
date
pay_period
borrower_id
lender_id
```

the user table

```
users
-----
id
name
phone
```

this is the sql i have

```
Select
  loans.amt,
  loans.date,
  loans.pay_period,
  borrower.phone As borrower_phone,
  borrower.name As borrower_name,
  lender.phone As lender_phone,
  lender.name As lender_name,
From
  loans Left Join
  users borrower On borrower.id = loans.borrower_id Left Join
  users lender On lender.id = loans.lender_id
Where
   lender.phone = '12345678' or borrower.phone = '12345678'
```

the expected output is

```
amt,
date,
pay_period,
borrower_phone,
borrower_name,
lender_phone,
lender_name,
```

this returns results for only lender.phone ="12345678", but if i add the borrower.phone ="12345678", it does not return result for this same phone as borrower

Any advice will be appreciated

Comment: It looks like you trimmed down the table info so we don't have to sift through a bunch of extra info (thank you), but you reference some fields in your query that aren't in your table. Since you aren't getting an error, I'm guessing `loans.borrower_id`, `loans.lender_id`, and `users.id` do exist but just aren't listed?

Comment: My suggestion would be to post some sample data for each table and the desired result of the query.

Comment: @Smith . . . Your query looks correct for retrieving data where either the lender or the borrower match that phone number.  Hence, I conclude that I don't understand what you really want.  Follow bluefeet's advice and post sample data with expected results.

Comment: Your query seems correct. Do you have more conditions in the `WHERE` clause besides these 2? If yes, try putting parentheses around these 2: `Where (lender.phone = '12345678' or borrower.phone = '12345678') AND ... other_conditions`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is correct.  You might want to take a look at how you are populating the data in the underlying tables.  If you are using the SELECT statement you proposed as a table for direct edit in some GUI, it could be getting confused about how to create the 2 distinct Users rows to store the data.

Anyway, I reconstructed your example in MySQL, populated the 2 tables as follows:

```
insert into `users` (name, phone) values ('Borrower01', '123456789');
insert into `users` (name, phone) values ('Borrower02', '234567890');
insert into `users` (name, phone) values ('Borrower03', '345678901');
insert into `users` (name, phone) values ('Borrower04', '456789012');

insert into `users` (name, phone) values ('Lender03', '123456789');
insert into `users` (name, phone) values ('Lender04', '234567890');
insert into `users` (name, phone) values ('Lender01', '345678901');
insert into `users` (name, phone) values ('Lender02', '456789012');

insert into loans (amt,date,pay_period,borrower_id,lender_id)
values (100.00, '2013-04-01', '2013-04-15',1,7)

insert into loans (amt,date,pay_period,borrower_id,lender_id)
values (100.00, '2013-04-01', '2013-04-15',2,8)

insert into loans (amt,date,pay_period,borrower_id,lender_id)
values (100.00, '2013-04-01', '2013-04-15',3,5)

insert into loans (amt,date,pay_period,borrower_id,lender_id)
values (100.00, '2013-04-01', '2013-04-15',4,6)
```

So, loans 1 and 3 should be returned by your query.

```
Select
  loans.amt,
  loans.date,
  loans.pay_period,
  borrower.phone As borrower_phone,
  borrower.name As borrower_name,
  lender.phone As lender_phone,
  lender.name As lender_name
From
  loans Left Join
  users borrower On borrower.id = loans.borrower_id Left Join
  users lender On lender.id = loans.lender_id 
Where
   lender.phone = '123456789' 
    or 
    borrower.phone = '123456789'
```

This returned:

```
amt, date, pay_period, borrower_phone, borrower_name, lender_phone, lender_name
100, 2013-04-01, 2013-04-15, 123456789, Borrower01, 345678901, Lender01
100, 2013-04-01, 2013-04-15, 345678901, Borrower03, 123456789, Lender03
```

So, your query is properly formed.  Check your data.